# How do you change the font of an NSTextView without changing the current content?

Tags: cocoa, macos, fonts, nstextview

Everytime I use -setFont: or -setFont:Range: on my NSTextView, it does change the font, but it shouldn't. I just want to change the font the user is typing with.

For example, if the user types 'hi' it uses the default Helvetica font. When I change the font to Times New Roman it changes that 'hi' into Times New Roman. I don't want that. I just want that, from now on, when the user types, Times New Roman is used instead of Helvetica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might want to use `-[NSTextView setTypingAttributes:]` instead. You should also make sure your text view is set as rich text.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem.